# onget handler razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a button on a GET Form on asp.net core razor pages

```
<form method="get" asp-page="Index">
<button type="submit" asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="Something" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
</form>
```

and the code behind

```
public IActionResult OnGetSomething(){
//... some code
return Page();
}
```

My problem is the onget handler code is never executed
If the form is POST the onpost handler will work fine but if it is GET it doesn’t work

So what am I missing here? and how to make the onget handler work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you submit a form using `GET`, the browser trashes query string values in the form action and replaces them with a new query string built from the form fields. You can hit your handler by adding an appropriate hidden field to the form:

```
<form method="get" asp-page="Index">
    <input type="hidden" name="handler" value="Something" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This method will hit regardless of which button clicked on the form, I need somthing like `OnPost[handler]Async` scheme like on this documentation
 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I managed to do it by adding the “hidden” input attributes to the desired button

`<button type="submit" name="handler" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary">ClearResult</button>`

Comment: Mike, how did you find this out? Can you explain in more detail what and why this happens, or maybe provide a link about it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can't go to get method because of parameters miss matching.
Suppose:

**In controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
//Post Method
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string Name)
        {
        }
```

**In View:**

```
<form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>]

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Then it go post method cause it has 1 parameters (Name). if we not net any input or parameters are not same then it hit different method.

**It the concept of method overloading**

In details of method overloading https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overloading/

Comment: This might apply to an MVC app, but the question is about Razor Pages which works differently.