# How to submit a GET form in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages

I have a razor page that has a form. When the page first loads, it hits the default `OnGet()` handler. I also want to be able to submit the form on the page to a different OnGet handler, `OnGetFormSubmit()`, in which I can requery data to repopulate the page model properties and load the page again. The reason for splitting this is because I am refactoring and it should simplify logic in the page handlers.

To be clear, I don't want to use `method="post"` on the form because I'm not performing any action like deleting or updating a record - I'm just reloading the page with new data.

I think I could technically submit it to an OnPost() handler and then redirect to `OnGetFormSubmit()` with the submitted values, but the POST feels like a needless middleman.

I tried making a form with `method="get"` and specifying the page handler, but when I submit the form it hits the `OnGet()` handler and not `OnGetFormSubmit()`.

From a design standpoint, does this make sense? How can I get it all to work?

HTML:

```
<form method="get" asp-page-handler="FormSubmit" >
   <input asp-for="Name" />

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PageModel:

```
public class PersonModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // set up model
    }

    public void OnGetFormSubmit()
    {
        // set up model
    }
}
```

The rendered HTML form:

```
<form method="get" action="/Person?handler=FormSubmit">
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" value="">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the **rendered HTML** of your `<form>`.

Comment: @Dai, I have posted it.

Comment: Hmm, everything you've posted looks like it _should_ work. Is anything altering your requests somewhere (such as middleware/filters/etc?). What happens if you create a new, empty, ASP.NET Core project with only this page added to it? Also, what version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: A new project had the same issue. I did manage to find the [reason and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769590/12300287) for what is happening. I tested this and it worked. Do you know if I should still keep this question up and submit an answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387117/should-i-delete-my-answer-thats-effectively-a-duplicate

Comment: Since the other question was hard to find because it isn't descriptive, I will keep my question up if my submitted edit to the other question is declined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason and solution in another thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769590/12300287)).

From that solution:

> When you submit a form using GET, the browser trashes query string
> values in the form action and replaces them with a new query string
> built from the form fields. You can hit your handler by adding an
> appropriate hidden field to the form:

In my case, the solution is to modify the HTML like so:

```
<form method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="handler" value="FormSubmit" />

   <input asp-for="Name" />

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```